# Spark's .count() function is different to the contents of the dataframe when filtering on corrupt record field

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark job, written in Python, which is getting odd behaviour when checking for errors in its data. A simplified version is below:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField, DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[3]").appName("pyspark-unittest").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")


SCHEMA = StructType([
    StructField("headerDouble", DoubleType(), False),
    StructField("ErrorField", StringType(), False)
])

dataframe = (
    spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
    .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "ErrorField")
    .schema(SCHEMA).csv("./x.csv")
)

total_row_count = dataframe.count()
print("total_row_count = " + str(total_row_count))

errors = dataframe.filter(col("ErrorField").isNotNull())
errors.show()
error_count = errors.count()
print("errors count = " + str(error_count))
```

The csv it is reading is simply:

```
headerDouble
wrong
```

The relevant output of this is

```
total_row_count = 1
+------------+----------+
|headerDouble|ErrorField|
+------------+----------+
|        null|     wrong|
+------------+----------+

errors count = 0
```

Now how does this possibly happen? If the dataframe has a record, how is being counted as 0? Is this a bug in the Spark infrastructure or am I missing something?

EDIT: Looks like this might be a known bug on Spark 2.2 which has been fixed in Spark 2.3 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21610

Comment: Definitely a bug. Based on the execution plan and behavior likely somewhere in the pushdown mechanism. Conisder `dataframe.select(col("ErrorField").isNotNull()).show()` vs. `dataframe.select("*", col("ErrorField").isNotNull()).show()`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks @user6910411 - does seem to be a bug. I've raised an issue in the Spark project's bug tracker.

I'm speculating that Spark is getting confused due to the presence of the `ErrorField` in the schema which is also being specified as the error column and being used to filter the dataframe.

Meanwhile I think I've found a workaround to count the dataframe rows at a reasonable speed:

```python
def count_df_with_spark_bug_workaround(df):
    return sum(1 for _ in df.toLocalIterator())
```

Not quite sure why this gives the right answer when `.count()` doesn't work.

Jira ticket I raised: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24147

This turned out to be a duplicate of:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21610

Comment: which spark version are you using? I am asking because I am getting `AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column`

Comment: Thanks, this was Spark 2.2-point-something. Looks like this was already "fixed" in the sense of giving an error message in 2.3 branch.